# Can I submit code written in Swift 4 to the App Store with Xcode 8.3.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, swift4

I would like to use the Xcode 9 beta for use in development but I can't seem to get the correct settings for using Swift 3.2 within Xcode 9. The editor is much quicker than Xcode 8.3.2

I can [(and have) downloaded](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/05/whats-new-in-swift-4-playground/) the [Swift 4 toolchain from swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#swift-40-development) and can use it from within both Xcode 8.3 and the Xcode 9 beta. If I wanted to ship my app before Xcode 9 is officially released, could I write it in Swift 4 and then submit it to the App Store via Xcode 8.3 using the Swift 4 toolchain?

Comment: Apple usually opens up submissions for the next version of iOS a couple weeks before it's release. That's when you'll be able to use Xcode 9 and Swift 4 with app submissions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot submit a binary that contains code built with the Swift 4 toolchain (or any development toolchain for that matter) to the Apple App Store using Xcode 8.3.2.

Jordan Rose, a Swift compiler engineer at Apple, [tweeted](https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/874359078314582016):

> Development toolchains are never used when submitting to the store, sorry! (We want to avoid XcodeGhost-like scenarios.)

Thus, this configuration is not supported and you will need to wait for Xcode 9 to ship projects using Swift 4.  Your binary will be rejected.

Comment: Any idea if this applies to release toolchains as well? e.g. if I use the Swift 4.1 release toolchain in an older version of Xcode would that be ok?

Comment: Update: Jordan Rose responded that also doesn't work: https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/982078239936995329